# How to find the parent of item when clicked in empty space PyQt4 QTreeWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

Didn't quite know how to word this but here i go,

This part of the program displays the folders found in a directory and subdirectorys in a QTreeWidget (It loads them fine) I would like the ability to create new folders no matter the depth in the tree. For example say i have the directory:

```
data\examples\folders\
```

and i right click in the empty space in the QTreeWidget below the folders branch, i want the ability to create a folder below it so the directory becomes:

```
data\examples\folder\untitled\
```

I have the context menu working but cannot understand how to implement a way to place the new folder item at a specific depth as i do not know the parent of the area i clicked

Here is my code (only retentive parts):

```
self.treelist = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
self.treelist.setHeaderLabels(["Name"])
self.treelist.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
self.treelist.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.openContextMenu)
```

And the openContextMenu function

```
def openContextMenu(self,point):

    addFolder = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("data\\icons\\folder.png"), "&New Folder", self)
    addFolder.triggered.connect(self.addFolderToList)

    item = self.treelist.itemAt(point)

    #Current Mouse Pos

    cpos = QtGui.QCursor()

    #Context Menu

    contextMenu = QtGui.QMenu(self)

    #Context Menu Actions

    contextMenu.addAction(self.addFolder)

    contextMenu.exec_(cpos.pos())
```

What i want to happen is when the addFolder action is triggered a folder will be created beneath the parent of the area i clicked.

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Why not do the most obvious and intuitive thing and right-click the items themselves to add child items? Empty areas don't have a parent item (naturally).

Comment: @ekhumoro I see where you are coming from but for example in windows explorer you can right click in an empty space. That is what im looking for, just a nice feature not necessary

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "empty space"? In a tree-view, each item extends the full width of the view. The only truly empty space (where `itemAt()` returns `None`) is at the bottom of the view. So the "owner" of that area can be taken as either the last item, or the root item.